# Set the connection string as an absolute path in the application code

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

**I use:**

- Console;
- .Net Framework 4.7.2;
- SQLite.

**The current method of setting the DB connection string:**

- SQLite is located next to the application file(`*.exe`);
- I'm setting the connection string in `App.config`.

**App.config**
`<connectionStrings>     <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\dbSqLite02.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>    </connectionStrings>`

**DbContextApplication.cs**

```
class DbContextApplication : DbContext
{
    public DbContextApplication() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    
    public DbSet<Source> Sources { get; set; }      
}
```

**The desired way to set the DB connection string:**

- I give the application a list of paths to different databases;
- the application takes a path from the list and connects to the database.

**Questions:**

1. How to set an absolute path to the `SQLite` database in the application?
2. What should `DbContextApplication.cs` look like?
   Set the connection string as an absolute path in the application code.

[image]

Comment: Create a variable in the config file for the absolute path.  The connection string is a string and can be a combination of more than one variable.

Comment: @jdweng Could you give a complete example of the solution. What will it look like?
I don't really understand what it will look like..

Comment: <connectionStrings> is a variable name that is recognized in c#.  So you can add to the config file <absolutepath>.